# Text with bevelled edges that reflect light

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-effects, reflection

I am trying to achieve a text effect like this using Photoshop:

[image]

See how it has borders that can reflect light:

1. How do you do those edges?
2. How do I make the edges reflect light as per the top right of the letter o and  bottom left of the letter t?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing's really being "reflected."

I could be mistaken, but it appears to be a simple gradient stroke to me...

[image]

Comment: If you want to upload this somewhere and I'll sponsor your paypal, thanks heaps!

Comment: Upload it? I didn't save the file. It only takes a minute or two to create. All the information you need is in the screenshot above. And, thanks, but I don't help here to make money.

Comment: Also note, there is *no* "bevel & emboss* in my image, just the stroke, then *tight* inner and outer glows to add a little more contrast.